# Angular input limited to 1 char

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know why I can't input more than one character per input in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/R3uY4/2/

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
     <table>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="f in foo">
                    <input ng-model="foo[$index]" style="width:60px" ></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.foo = [];
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        $scope.foo.push('');
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are binding your model to a primitive. It can't work that way. Complete explanation in this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267). Also, your ng-repeat refreshes each time you change the input value. That's why you are loosing focus.

Always bind to objects:

HTML:

```
<td ng-repeat="f in foo">
  <input ng-model="f.value" style="width:60px" />
</td>
```

Controller:

```
function ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.foo = [];
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        $scope.foo.push({value: ''});
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this related to primitive being immutable and object references?

Comment: @plus-, the primitive is mutable.  It works this way because of the way JavaScript [prototypal inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482) works with Angular scopes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using HTML5 you can use the `autofocus` attribute. Just add it to the `input` field.

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.name}} <input ng-model="i.description" autofocus></li>
```

Here's a [fork of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/Ex3vk/).

Comment: Thanks that works, I'd like to understand why it switches input though

Comment: @plus-, the github link provided by Stewie explains the loss of focus -- see mhevery/Misko's first reply.